# How to change android app package name in fabrics dashboard for crashlytics

Tags: android, google-fabric, package-name

I was using crashlytics by fabric in my android app. While publishing app to playstore,i changed my android app package name. Now i want to change package name for the app in fabrics dashboard. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If an app changes package names, then it would be registered as a new app within Fabric. There is not currently a way to rename the package name of the app within Fabric.

**Edit**
To add a new app through Fabric, follow the steps [here](http://fabric.io/kits) for the SDK you're looking to install, then build and run the app after making the code changes.

Comment: Thanks, feel free to upvote or mark my answer as answered :)

Comment: @MikeBonnell Why does my Beta crashlytics reject my apk and insists it's using a module's package name (it's not....)

Comment: This seems to be an unrelated question, so I'd recommend posting a new question.

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell. If the previous package name was A and now its B. What should the dashboard show? In my case it shows A and B but all the events and data gets shown in A. Is there a way to changed the displayed package to B?

Comment: We group apps based on the API key of the Fabric organization, platform of the app, and package name of the app. If data isn't flowing into B, I'd make sure that you see B in the Fabric dashboard and that you've shipped that version of the app with the correct API key.

Comment: @MikeBonnell . I changed the Package name of my App in Android studio. Then I opened Fabric in Android Studio. But the "Select your Android Project" showing only the old package name with added status.

Comment: How can I add the app after changing package name?